# Is there a good reference available that explains the FacesMessage lifecycle?

Tags: jsf-2.2

I have been trying to use the h:messages component to display global messages. I have been unable to figure out how to reliably cause the messages to disappear once they are displayed.  I have seen many posts that talk about the same issue, but I have yet to find one that describes how the Faces message system works.

In particular, I wish to understand the conditions under which FaceMessages are dismissed, i.e., is it done by forcing a client-side ajax execute cycle, render cycle, or both on the component containing the message component? Is there a general way to do institute the appropriate cycles from a server-side backing bean that receives asynchronous updates to its model?  For example, I am using icefaces, and it provides a server-side ajax push feature that seems to provide some support for this, but it only appears to affect a single component when it occurs.  Also, what is the accepted practice to force a FacesMessage inserted by FacesContext.addMessage to be removed other than requesting a complete page refresh in the browser. I've had more success getting a FacesMessages generated via a validation exception to dismiss, but even that is not always reliable, and I would like to understand why.

Unfortunately, posting my application code will be difficult, because the system on which I do development is not connected to the internet. I am hoping at this point for someone to point me in the right direction so I can better understand how things should work. So if someone can describe the lifecycle of a FacesMessage in light of the preceding, or give me an authoritative reference to this information , I would be very appreciative.

Comment: Faces messages are request scoped. What then happens on the client once they're displayed is up to the client. Either remove the HTML element representing the faces message from the DOM using JS, or Ajax-update the message container. A more concrete answer is easier if you come up with a MCVE. This all is a bit too much a rant which is more fit for a blog rather than a Q&A site.

Comment: My apologies, I am a neophyte here and also in the JSF world.  It was not meant to be a rant, sorry if it sounded that way.  I have spent a good bit of time on my own trying to figure this out, but to this point, the subject matter appears to be quite arcane. Please explain what you mean by MCVE and I will try to provide it if I can.

Comment: Usually, users state the requirement, the code, the expectations and the observed problem symptoms and finally the (then obvious) question. No additional (personal) drama. As to asking the right question, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: I have edited the original post a bit  in response to BalusC's critique, but the gist of it remains the same.  I am looking for information here of a general nature about how FacesMessages are handled by the runtime.  And as I indicated, it will be difficult for me to provide the code I have written, as I would have to print it out and enter it here by hand, with all the likely typos that would ensue. Before I take that step, I was hoping the information I provided was clear enough that someone could point me to a text or web reference that could help me better understand this subject area.

Answer (score 1):

Building on some work I found by BalusC (http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html and http://balusc.blogspot.com/2012/03/reset-non-processed-input-components-on.html), I was able to create a PhaseListener that logged sufficient information about what happens in the FacesMessage world to understand why my approach was failing.

The approach I took was to use a "Reset" button to clear the currently displayed messages (displayed in a h:messages component).  I was using the "actionListener" callback in my backing bean to clear the messages (which can be accessed via the two FacesContext.getMessages methods), but even though the messages were displayed, the message data structures were always empty.

Turns out my problem was Phase related.  The "actionListener" callback runs in the INVOKE_APPLICATION Phase, but the message data structures do not become populated until the RENDER_RESPONSE phase. By creating an appropriately coded PhaseListener, I am now able to defer clearing the message data structures until the RENDER_RESPONSE phase, which works perfectly.

I should add that the second BalusC link I cited above is also very important when messages occur due to failures raised from the PROCESS_VALIDATIONS phase, as input components will remain in their invalid state until they are reset, and he provides a very nice method for doing so.

Again, I apologize for not being able to post actual code, as my development system is disconnected from the internet and I am prohibited from taking anything out on removable media.